# what is the intersection/union between ado.net and dapper?

Tags: orm, ado.net, dapper

What is the intersection/union between ADO.NET and Dapper?  From what I can tell so far, Dapper essentially seems to extend an ADO.NET implementation. So when using Dapper, which parts of ADO.NET get used and carried over and which parts of ADO.NET get replaced or extended with a Dapper-specific implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Dapper is a micro-OR/M. It's built on top of ADO.NET, it doesn't extend ADO.NET.

While it's a very short answer, there's no more to explain, and for low-level details about how Dapper is implemented, [you should take a look at its source code.](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper)